# java char array to String with spaces

Tags: java

I'm trying something like a crossword puzzle. in a 5 by 5 grid.
25 of them have different letters in them, 1 is the submit button. So whenever i hit the submit button. It will do something like this. str is the word that i retrieve from a text file, and guess is the char array.

```
           if (count == str.length())
           {
              String a = String.copyValueOf(guess);
             a= a.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");  


              if (str.equals(a))
              {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! Well Done!");
                  score += 10;
                  totalScore.setText ("Score: " + score);

              }
              else
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again");
```

the thing is, whether the answer is correct or not, it will only display "please try again". It can work if i change my array size to [5], but if it goes out of bound if i click 6 buttons. Anyone can tell me what's wrong with this?

edit: i added a messageDialog, and it display jump with tons of spaces at the back

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "|" + a + "|" + str + "|");
```

Changing it to

```
a= a.replace(" ", "");
```

doesn't work too.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of *str* and *a*? Pop them out to a message dialog or use a logger.

Comment: no problem with str. however for a, tons of spaces at the back.  a= a.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");  doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to remove white spaces from a String, try using the String's trim() function.

Comment: Or if you want to use RegExps, use a= a.replaceAll("(.*)\\s+$", "\\1"); because Java RegExps are always applied to the full string. I personally would go for trim() as Matthias suggested :)

Comment: Why are you comparing the char array. Can answers be horizontal and vertical? Can answers be anywhere? What is guess - array of 1 dimension? Hows does the 5x5 grid fit in to it?

Why not use a array of [5][5] ? or a string array?

Answer (score 0):

Use trim() function. The easiest method to trim spaces from a string.